# Missing spacing after ' (apostrophe)

Tags: fontspec

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

\begin{document}

L'arbre. L'enfant.

D'ailleurs. M'aborder comme ça !

\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image]

There is a missing space after "L'", but it's OK with "D'" or "M'".

I'm using the default font declarations from TeXShop for XeTeX, and the problem goes away if I skip them. But I'd like to use Hoefler Text!

Comment: It's a precise choice of the font designer, who decided to kern L and the apostrophe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a precise decision made by the font designer: the apostrophe is kerned against the uppercase L.

If you don't want this kerning, insert `\/` between the two characters.

By the way, you're using very old style font declarations and it's better to change to the current ones.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

%\usepackage{fontspec} % polyglossia loads it
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

\begin{document}

L\/'arbre. L\/'enfant.

D'ailleurs. M'aborder comme ça!

\texttt{---}% no ligatures

\end{document}
```

Note that `Mapping=tex-text` should be called as `Ligatures=TeX`, but it's not necessary as `fontspec` applies it by default (except for the `mono` font). Don't load `xunicode`; you may load `xltxtra`, but it doesn't really add any useful feature (and might do evil, in some cases).

Note also that you shouldn't have a space in front of `!`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the space before `!`, it's standard in French. Do you mean that I should ignore the French convention in the source code and let LaTeX manage it?

Comment: @Blacksad Yes, that's how you're supposed to do with polyglossia